# Scala: MapReduce on Array

Tags: scala

I have an array

```
Array(1, 2, 3, 5)
```

I need to calculate all subtractions to get a new list

```
Array(1, 1, 2) // Array(2-1, 3-2, 5-3)
```

It is very easy to implement if you are using `sliding` and `mapping`

```
(xs sliding 2).toList map { case List(x, y) => y - x }
```

But what If I want to calculate this via MR? Is it possible? As for me, I don't see any possibility to do that. Maybe there is some other ideas?

Comment: I can use MR only to calculate something like this: `Array(1, 2, 3, 5).map(_ * 2).reduce((x, y) => y - x)`. But it is not a subtraction array.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
list.zip(list.drop(1)).map { case(x,y) => y-x }
```

You can also do it with `foldRight`:

```
list.foldRight(List.empty[Int]) {
  case (x, Nil) => List(x)
  case (x, y :: tail) => x :: (y - x) :: tail
}.drop(1)
```

But may I ask what is it that you are really trying to do here?

Or, if you insist on only using `map` and `reduce` for some obscure reason (what would that be), something like this will work:

```
 list
  .map { x => List(x) }
  .reduce { (a,b) => 
    b.head :: (b.head - a.head) :: a.tail 
  }.drop(1).reverse
```

This really is cheating though, because the function you give to `reduce` must be commutative and associative, and this case it is neither. 
It just happens to work in toy applications, because there is no parallelism, but do not attempt to use this in real life, because it will probably break very badly ... and also because there is no reason to do that.

Comment: I'm playing with `MR` on arrays.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "MR"? Using only "map" and "reduce" and nothing else? Because this is not what this term normally means.

Comment: Yes, I want to use `map` and `reduce` functions. And yes, I mean `MR` in this sense.

Comment: The point is you _should not_ "want" it, because it makes no sense.
It's akin to asking a question "how do I find a factorial of a number using only addition and subtraction?"

Comment: @dima, you rang? `def mul(n:Int,m:Int, tot:Int=0):Int = if (n ==0) tot else mul(n-1, m, tot + m);
def fac(n:Int):Int = if (n == 1) 1 else mul(n, fac(n-1))`. But I agree with your comment  more generally!

Comment: @The Archetypal Paul Sure. I did not say it was impossible ... Just impractical. BTW, you are not only using addition here ... Also recursion, conditionals, function calls ...

Comment: Completely agree. It was a fun 5 min puzzle though